# Trying to locate/convert PEM file from SSL zip

Tags: mongodb, ssl, docker-compose, tls1.2

I am not understanding this SSL pem file issue. I am trying to secure a mongo instance with a cert. One of the parameters I need to pass is the pem file.

```
--tlsCertificateKeyFile=/data/ssl/mysite.pem
```

The trouble is the zip file I got from the CA does not have a .pem file. However reading google articles it would appear I just need to rename one of the cert files to .pem? I've tried several BUT NOT ALL with no success. In trying these files I also remove the line breaks so it is all one line.

Here is what I got in the zip file.

STAR_mysite_com.key

```
-----BEGIN PRIVATE KEY-----ABCD1234.....-----END PRIVATE KEY-----
```

STAR_mysite_com.csr

```
-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE REQUEST-----ABCD1234....-----END CERTIFICATE REQUEST-----
```

*wildcard*.mysite.com.crt (I'm guessing this one is the whole chain as it has 4 sections)

```
-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----ABCD1234.....-----END CERTIFICATE-----
-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----ZXCT1345.....-----END CERTIFICATE-----
-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----KJLY9573.....-----END CERTIFICATE-----
-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----QPOD6732.....-----END CERTIFICATE-----
```

USERTrustRSAAAACA.crt

```
-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----ABCD1234....-----END CERTIFICATE-----
```

AAACertificateServices.crt

```
-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----ABCD1234....-----END CERTIFICATE-----
```

DNEncryptSHA2DVSSLTLS

```
-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----ABCD1234....-----END CERTIFICATE-----
```

STAR_mysite_com

```
-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----ABCD1234....-----END CERTIFICATE-----
```

To give further context, I am at getting this error from what I have tried so far:

> error:0909006C:PEM routines:get_name:no start line"

Google tells me I simply need to use the correct pem file.

So which one is my pem file OR which one do I use for one of the online converters to create my pem file?

Comment: *In trying these files I also remove the line breaks so it is all one line.*  Ummm, why?  If you don't know what you're doing, why are you modifying the file format at all?

Answer (score 0):

OK I figured it out.

So this link was really helpful.

[https://docs.progress.com/bundle/datadirect-hybrid-data-pipeline-installation-46/page/PEM-file-format.html#:~:text=A%20PEM%20file%20must%20consist,make%20up%20the%20trust%20chain.&text=A%20PEM%20encoded%20file%20includes,%2D%2D%2D%2D%2D%22](https://docs.progress.com/bundle/datadirect-hybrid-data-pipeline-installation-46/page/PEM-file-format.html#:%7E:text=A%20PEM%20file%20must%20consist,make%20up%20the%20trust%20chain.&text=A%20PEM%20encoded%20file%20includes,%2D%2D%2D%2D%2D%22).

The problem was that a pem file format is an aggregation of all the different crt files.

I took the key and put that at the start and the wildcard crt next so my pem looked like this....and it worked.

> mysite.pem

```
-----BEGIN PRIVATE KEY-----ABCD1234.....-----END PRIVATE KEY-----
-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----ABCD1234.....-----END CERTIFICATE-----
-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----ZXCT1345.....-----END CERTIFICATE-----
-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----KJLY9573.....-----END CERTIFICATE-----
-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----QPOD6732.....-----END CERTIFICATE-----
```